# My label.width is going negative

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm coding my own chart because the predefined chart can't handle the type of values I want to use. For the lines I'm using colored labels with different width.
To print the chart I'm using this method:

```
labelSize = new Size();
labelSize.Height = 35;
Size maxSize = new Size(214783647, 500);

labelSize.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ShiftPts[i + 1].timeint - ShiftPts[i].timeint);
Label l1 = new Label();
l1.MaximumSize = maxSize;
l1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
Point LabelPoint = new Point(tempStartX, StartPositionY);
//Point LabelPoint = new Point(tempStartX, StartPositionY);
l1.Size = labelSize;
l1.Location = LabelPoint;
l1.Text = ShiftPts[i].Status;
tempStartX = tempStartX + labelSize.Width;

BoxLine.Add(l1);
```

The `tempStartX` variable is an `int`, which you can see increases on every looptick. The issue with this variable is that it gets negative because of the label's width. Whenever I try to specify a width over 390 something, the width simply goes negative. Why does that happen?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What's in `ShiftPts[i].timeint`? If that value is a big number, it'll result in a negative label width.

Comment: Yes i have been debugging it. And it can be big numbers yes. Why does that result in a negative width?

Comment: ShiftPts[i + 1].timein will never be less than ShiftPts[i].timeint

Comment: They represent time, so they always increase

Comment: "Width goes negative"...meaning that in debug you watch `labelSize.Width` become a negative value?  If so, on precisely what line does that occur?  If you mean something else, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ShiftPts[i + 1].timeint` is less than `ShiftPts[i].timeint` then `labelSize.Width` will be negative. You then assign this value to `tempStartX`.

Since this seems to be the only place where you subtract, this can be the only reason why your variable is set to a negative value.

Another possibility is that `tempStartX` is already negative.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment `ShiftPts[i + 1].timeint`, will never be less than `ShiftPts[i].timeint`

Comment: @JakobDanielsson Are you sure about that? That's the only place where you subtract in your code. It's also possible that `tempStartX` is already negative. Have you checked that? Your code sample doesn't show how it's set before it's used.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, i thought that i sorted the elements in `ShiftPts` after time, but apperently i were wrong. Thank you!